# Missing tray icon indicator in recent Spotify versions?

Tags: indicator, system-tray, spotify

I installed the latest Spotify version `1.0.14.124.g4dfabc51`. I noticed that version `=> 1.0` no longer seem to show a tray icon indicator, and thus their windows cannot be minimised.

Is there a way to bring back the tray icon indicator in these versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the tray icon *cannot* be enabled for the 1.0.x client at this time. The issue appears to be longstanding, and is so mentioned at the Spotify community forums: ["Linux Spotify client 1.x now in stable"](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Windows-Web/Linux-Spotify-client-1-x-now-in-stable/m-p/1300404/highlight/true#M151493)

Regarding bugs/issues in 1.0.23:

> Most of these we want to fix, but others (like missing tray icon) we probably won't.

For now, Spotify is not willing/able to devote enough development resources to the Linux client. I have remained on the "spotify-client-0.9.17" package, while periodically checking the functionality of the 1.0.x testing releases (I have both the "stable" and "testing" repositories). The '0.9.17' client is disappointingly flakey sometimes (esp. "Spotify Helper" processes), but it still gives me a tray icon and panel info/support with 14.04.

Comment: good would be to add a link to Spotify's expression...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround

You will need kdocker

Edit the shortcut to spotify to run a similar command :

```
kdocker -q -t -i /usr/share/icons/Papirus-Greytika-Alt/32x32/apps/spotify-client.svg spotify
```

"-q" : Disable notification generated by kdocker

"-t" : Hide spotify from task bar

"-i" : Specify a custom tray icon

Answer (score 0):

Open the unity tweak tool and goto Unity->Panel->Volume->Default Player and select Spotify.desktop.

This worked out for me.

Comment: interesting. For me there is no "Spotify.desktop" option to choose from.